# Rails validation- confirmation not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying confirmation validation in Rails4 but it does not work correctly.
When i submit the form the message is "Email confirmation can't be blank" instead of "Email doesn't match confirmation"
Here is my code:

```
enter code here
#model user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :email, confirmation: true
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
end

#view     
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email_confirmation %><br>
<%= f.text_field :email_confirmation %>
</div>
#controller
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
respond_to do |format|
if @user.save
format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully    created.' }
format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
else
format.html { render :new }
format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
```

Comment: Where is the field for `email`? I can see only `email_confirmation` here... and presence validation will give "can't be blank" message.

Comment: <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom validation to check if two fields are the same

```
validate :check_email

def check_email
  errors.add(:email_comfirmation, "Test message") if email == email_confirmation
end
```